# FIrefox resize grip / gripper

Tags: firefox, window, size

I have been a Firefox user almost since its inception. One thing that frustrates me in the more recent versions is that the bottom-right "resize grip" has been taken away. I'm talking about the small area in the bottom-right of the main window, which can be used to drag the window to a different size. Otherwise, you're left having to place the mouse perfectly on the corner - which can be awkward.

I have searched add-ons and the web (including this site), and can only find reference to a resize grip for a text box. Not the whole Firefox program itself.

Like this:

[image: Like this]

Any add-on, or other code suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: On modern flat [read: appallingly poorly designed] GUIs, the functionality tends to still be there but present no hint to the user. Try it. if you're lucky you may see a hint of double-arrow cursor as you hover the 4 pixels they left for the task… all in the name of 'cleanliness'.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Yes, I know there is a double arrow in the VERY SMALL bottom-right corner. I'm not saying it's impossible to resize the Firefox window: just that it's very awkward, hence the request for a "gripper" area.

Comment: I'd imagine the OS is in charge of that; that's what's responsible for building the window itself. macOS is similar these days, there's no indicator but the double arrow on hover - though they do give you a reasonably large grab-able area in most cases.